# Determine if back button clicked in Kendo Mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

In my view, I want to perform an action unless the user got there with a back button. Is there a way to determine in the view if the source request was from a back button or not?

Here is the view's show I event I am trying to do it in:

```
<div data-role="view" data-show="onShow"...>...</div>

onShow: function (e) {
  if (???) { //How to determine if user came via back button or not
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to handle back button in your application.

```
/*
Device Back Button Handling of all html pages                      
*/
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);            
function deviceInfo() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, true);
} 

function onBackButton() {
    var item = app.view().id;
        switch (item) {
                 case "index.html"
                 /*your scenario*/
                 break;
                 case "2ndpage.html"
                 /*your scenario*/
                 break;

}
```

Comment: I was also able to find a private property I can use, not sure how dependable it is to rely on tho: e.view._back